# Static member initialization across systems

Tags: c++, static, cross-platform

If I have the following class:

```
class Base {
protected:
    std::uint32_t generateId() {
        return TYPE_COUNTER++;
    }
private:
    static std::uint32_t TYPE_COUNTER;
}
static std::uint32_t Base::TYPE_COUNTER = 0;
```

And then in the derived classes I would have:

```
class Child : public Base {
public:
    static std::uint32_t getId() {
        return TYPE_ID;
    }
private:
    static const std::uint32_t TYPE_ID;
};
const std::uint32_t Child::TYPE_ID = Base::generateId();
```

Assuming that code is in a shared static library between the client and the server, can I guarantee that the child classes will end up with the same number on the server and client and across different platforms?

Comment: With great difficulty. If you're designing a wire format, you need to document that format publicly, and that probably involves picking actual values and hard-coding those. What if someone wants to write a client in a different language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of initialization of global objects is only defined with one translation unit. If all your global objects are in one translation they are initialized in the same order on all systems and the objects get the same ideas.

The order of initialization between translation units is unspecified. A DS9k implementation can choose to initialize translation units in a different order each time the program is run on the same same system or randomly change the order when the run-time suspects you are demonstrating the product to a client. That is, even on one system you can't guarantee the order of initialization and certainly not between two systems.

It seems you are defining a wire-format. You **do not** want to depend on subtle changes to your source code to change something like IDs! Even if you don't want to publicly advertise the IDs, you certainly want to nail them down: once you have a mildly successful piece of code in production, these IDs will be as fixed as chiseled in stone (actually, it is more like that you could manage to recast the stone than changing a production system without disruption). Note that I'm talking from theoretical considerations but from practical experience! I have worked on systems which took short-cuts similar to yours and which were successful and which were as a result very hard to change!

Answer (score 0):

Not if the client and server are in separate processes.  For each process the sequence of Id's handed out to Child instances will simply be sequential. If all clients happen to have exactly the same number of Child instances as the server, then they will all have the same set of id's.

Comment: I want to serialize the data in the Child class, and send it over the network to the clients and use the generated id as a way to determine how it should be deserialized. If it really comes down to it, I could create an enumeration of child classes and hardcode it. If I can get away without the extra inconvenience, then that would be best.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to transmit data from Server to Client and attach a unique ID to each data batch indicating how to deserialise it.

(You might also want to transmit Client to Server or even Client to Client).

This sounds a little like a HTTP mime type.  Could you, in fact, use a mime type?

One other possibility would be to create a file (maybe XML??) that contains a list of IDs and method to decode them.  The file could be installed with each client or server, or the server could transmit it, on request, to each client -- possibly transmitting updated versions as time goes on.

If there is some shared disk space, you could just have one (read-only) file shared between all Clients -- but that may not be practical, depending on your network architecture.

If the above doesn't help, perhaps you could describe your requirement in more detail?